# Two versions of SSH

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, raspbian, openssh

I have installed OpenSSH 7.5p1 on my Raspberry Pi from [Debian](https://packages.qa.debian.org/o/openssh.html). I installed it using `wget`, the `tar -zxvf openssh_7.5p1.orig.ta.gz`, `cd openssh_7.5p1`, `./configure`, `make`, `sudo make install`.

When I do my security scan it says *6.7p1*. Command output for:

```
ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.15t 3 May 2016
```

and

```
/usr/bin/ssh -V
OpenSSH_6.7p1, Raspbian-5+deb8u3, OpenSSL 1.0.15t 3 May 2016
```

When I do `sudo dpkg --list openssh*` it shows it using *6.7p1*.

I deleted `/usr/bin/ssh` and linked it to `/usr/local/bin/ssh`. And now it shows:

```
OpenSSH_7.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.15t 3 May 2016
```

But the `sudo dpkg --list openssh*` still shows *6.7p1*. I need it to scan and see only the *7.5p1*.

Running `whereis ssh` gives `ssh: /usr/bin/ssh /etc/ssh /usr/local/bin/ssh /usr/share/man/man1/ssh.1.vs` and `which ssh` shows `/usr/local/bin/ssh`

Ok I used `apt-get purge` to purge all instances of ssh, and reinstalled 7.5p1 as before. 7.5 is still in my `/usr/local/bin`. I linked `/usr/bin/ssh` to `/usr/local/bin/ssh` again. Now when I run `sudo dpkg --list openssh*` it show no instance of ssh, and I can't start the ssh service.

Is there anyway to fix this issue?

Comment: Show output of `whereis ssh`, `which ssh`

Comment: Whereis ssh shows ssh: /usr/bin/ssh /etc/ssh /usr/local/bin/ssh /usr/share/man/man1/ssh.1.vs and which ssh shows /usr/local/bin/ssh

Comment: Is your security scan looking at network ports (ie the server)? You've only told us about the ssh client.

Comment: Its looking at port. Am really talking about both.

Comment: You'll want to `dpkg -purge openssh` to get rid of the packaged version, and all it's cruft.

Comment: Why are you installing a different version? You should keep the one from the distribution. Installing your own is a security risk unless you diligently apply security updates.

Comment: Except that 6.7p1 is a huge security risk, which is what came with it. My security scan won't pass unless its 7.5p1 as all before it are considered at risk.

Comment: You need to install whatever script(s) your distro needs to manager "services". Doing `make install` won't install any scripts whatsoever. For example, if you use systemd look at:
 [Archlinux openssh build](https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk?h=packages/openssh).

Answer (score 1):

@edit

I would suggest removing the old instances and installing a fresh, latest version using this official [Repo](https://packages.qa.debian.org/o/openssh.html)

Comment: I used that install the 7.5 I have but the system didn't replace the 6.7 and its still running

Comment: have you removed the old version from the system beforehand?

Comment: I did, but then nothing ran

Comment: Looks like the user has two versions of ssh installed, one by package manager and another in `/usr/local`. Also only `ssh` mentioned, not `sshd`.

Comment: try to use "apt-get purge ssh*" and then check if any instance of ssh is still installed if not, install the latest version from the repo i have linked above. BEWARE, that after the purge you will have no ssh installed, therefore DO NOT close your ssh connection until you make sure, that you can connect to it in a new shell

Comment: Did the purge but when I try "dpkg --list openssh\*"  it still shows them there. I even rebooted. Looking at that page I can't figure out what distro I'm suppose to download.

Comment: Use Debian, since raspbian is based on debian.

Comment: I was installing it earlier with the "make" command should I still be doing it that way

Comment: first use ./configure, then make and finally make install

Comment: All versions on 6.7p1 are gone, and installed 7.5p1. 7.5 still installed in '/usr/local/bin', and the service won't start.

Comment: Is there any error?